# PySpark RDD SortByKey() Not Working Properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to sort an RDD that I have, which contains a key range of 0-49995 such that (0, value), ... , (49995, value).

I want to sort it in ascending order, and I am using the SortByKey() function, but it seems like it is not working properly because this is the result that I am getting:

> > > test0.sortByKey(True).take(5)

[(**u'0'**, [u'38737', u'18591', u'27383', u'34211', u'337', u'352', u'1532', u'12143', u'12561', u'17880']), (**u'1'**, [u'35621', u'44891', u'14150', u'15356', u'35630', u'13801', u'13889', u'14078', u'25228', u'13805']), (**u'10'**, [u'83', u'18', u'38', u'89', u'3', u'11', u'29', u'41', u'53', u'55']), (**u'100'**, [u'42704', u'122', u'125', u'128', u'131', u'2501', u'11200', u'12049', u'12576', u'18583']), (**u'1000'**, [u'8671', u'955', u'1012', u'1020', u'1378', u'2413', u'7699', u'10276', u'12625', u'12667'])]

It started at key 0, 1, but then skipped to 10 and jumped to 100, then 1000. It should ascending from 0-5. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sorting strings - as shown by the `u` prefix on the output (for Unicode, not that it really matters). Therefore it is working as `10` comes before `2` when tested as a string.

Map all your values to integers before working with them and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Philip! This makes a lot of sense. I am not familiar with how to go from where I am at, to mapping the String Keys into Integer Keys. Could you help me with an example?

Comment: Never mind, Philip. I figured out how, and it solved my problem. I did, test0.map(lambda x: (int(x[0], x[1])).take(5). Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I can't edit the previous comment, but there is a typo at the map function. This comment is for those who run into a similar problem: test0.map(lambda x: (int(x[0]), x[1])) is the proper map call. I was missing a closing parentheses after the int cast on x[0].